# Memory usage by images

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I am using scrollview as the parent view of the images each of 260X120 size.If I add even only 4-5 images on scrollview memory usage goes upto 3 MB to 4 MB and ultimately leads the app to crash.I am putting these images taken from the camera, resize them to the above written size.
Is there any way to manage this memory.I also ran the application on instruments and did not find any LEAK!

Here is the code which I am using:

```
-(void)displayLocalBadgesinScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollerView badgeArray:(NSMutableArray *)badgearray
{
//int count=0;

for(int i=countArrLast;i<[badgearray count];i++)
{
    if(count==2)
    {
        xGap=1.0;
        yGap=yGap+90;
        count=0;
    }
    UIButton *bdgButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    bdgButton.tag=i;
    bdgButton.frame=CGRectMake(xGap,yGap, 130.0, 70.0);
    BadgeDetail *object=[badgearray objectAtIndex:i];
    bdgButton.tag=[object.bdgID intValue];
    if([object badgeImage]!=nil)
    {
      [bdgButton addTarget:self action:@selector(markBadgeNew:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [bdgButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[Base64Coder decodeData:[object badgeImage]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }


    [scrollerView addSubview:bdgButton];
```

I am calling this method in view will appear when i move back from another screen only...and badgearray is filled with objects of BadgeDetail type.You can see how I am accessing image object from the object and setting as background image of the button.

Comment: 4 MB of memory would not make you app killed. Look else where for the crash.

Comment: You have a bug somewhere else.

Comment: i didnt say at 4MB my app is crashing, if i keep on adding images on scrollview eventually it gets crashed...say after 10-12 images!

Comment: You probably should post some of your code :)

Comment: Adi27, welcome to SO! Now: please reread your question - do you see any lack of information for others to help you? Don't take this the wrong way, but please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). We don't know anything about your application so all we can do is guess. You can edit your question at any time.

Comment: Also there is possible bug here - do not use `UIScrollView` for dynamic content. This will cause performance errors, because all your images will be loaded even if it not visible. Try to use `UITableView` with custom cells for this.

Comment: 10-12 images (about 15 mb?) still shouldn't be causing a crash from low memory, do as instructed above and look elsewhere for your problem.

Comment: I observed lot of temporary object in that view controller used some where else in loops....i guess they are taking memory...so looking on this.